# Estou com problemas para entender o async no flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:ouvinos_caprinos/especie/class/especie.dart';
    import 'package:ouvinos_caprinos/especie/db/especie_database.dart';
    import 'package:ouvinos_caprinos/ui/caprino/caprino_page.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      EspecieHelper _especieHelper = EspecieHelper();

      List<Especie> especies = List();
      @override
      void initState() {
        _getAllEspecies();
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Rebanhos Disponiveis"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              itemCount: especies.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return _especieDisponiveis(context, index);
              }),
        );
      }

      Widget _especieDisponiveis(BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 80.0,
                    height: 80.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                              "images/" + especies[index].descricao.toLowerCase() + ".png"),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          capitalize(especies[index].descricao + "s"),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            _goToPage(index);
          },
        );
      }

      void _goToPage(int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CaprinoPage(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                // builder: (context) => OvinoPage(),
                ),
          );
        }
      }

      String capitalize(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
          throw ArgumentError("string: $string");
        }

        if (string.isEmpty) {
          return string;
        }

        return string[0].toUpperCase() + string.substring(1);
      }

      Future<void> _getAllEspecies() async {
        await _especieHelper.getAllEspecies().then((listaE) {
          setState(() {
            especies = listaE;
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

bom eu estou tentando deixar meu app menos estático, estou pegando as informações de especies do meu banco de dados para melhorar a usabilidade e para futuras implementações, porém venho me deparando com tentativas falhas pois toda vez que eu inicio o app( pela primeira vez) o banco de dados especie é criado  até ai OK, mas ele não carrega as informações para a listview, so consigo visualiza-las depois de fechar o app e abrir de novo, alguem pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Num primeiro momento parece que o retorno de `_getAllEspecies()` só acontece depois de iniciar o estado Talvez usar um `FutureBuilder` resolva.

Comment: Eu tentei de diversas formas, usei o FutureBuilder para testar, mas não consegui, só aparecia depois de fechar o app e abrir dnv (no caso uma maneira de atualizar a pagina),  pode ser que eu não tenha entendido o conceito do FutureBuilder

Comment: Como está o método `_especieHelper.getAllEspecies()`?

Comment: `Future<List> getAllEspecies() async {
    Database dbEspecie = await db;
    List listMap = await dbEspecie.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
    List<Especie> listEspecie = List();
    for (Map m in listMap) {
      listEspecie.add(Especie.fromMap(m));
    }
    return listEspecie;
  }`

Comment: Certo, da para aplicar no FutureBuilder, vou deixar na resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendo como base o método

```dart
Future<List> getAllEspecies() async {
  Database dbEspecie = await db; List listMap = await dbEspecie.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
  List<Especie> listEspecie = List(); 
  for (Map m in listMap) { 
    listEspecie.add(Especie.fromMap(m)); 
  } 
 return listEspecie; 
}
```

Poderia ser usado em um FutureBuilder da seguinte forma:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext) {
  return Scaffold(
   ...

   body: FutureBuilder<List<Especie>>(
      future: _especieHelper.getAllEspecies(),
      builder: (BuildContext c, AsyncSnapshot<List<Especie>> snapshot) {
         if(snapshot.hasData) {
            // mostra a lista de especies
            return Column(
              children: snapshot.data.map(especie => ListTile(title: Text('Algum dado da especie $especie')))
            );
         }else if(snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Houve um erro ao listar as espécies');
         }else {
           return LinearProgressIndicator();
         }
      }

   )

  );
}
```

Veja que a gente passa a `future` para o FutureBuilder que vai tratar isso pra gente.

Assim a gente consegue validar se a Future já terminou, se ainda está em progresso ou se houve algum erro. Como é possível ver nas verificações.

Desse modo você não vai precisar fazer aquela listagem lá no `initState()`. Deixa a cargo do FutureBuilder mesmo.

### As verisicações

`snapshot.hasData` - Quando `true` significa que a Future completou-se e há um dado disponível

`snapshot.hasError` - Quando `true` significa que a Future gerou um erro

Se nenhuma das duas for true é porque a Future ainda está executando (nesse caso).

### Pegando o valor

Para recuperar o valor basta usar o `snapshot.data`. Isso vai te retornar o valor da Future, que nesse caso é um `List<Especie>`. Assim você pode fazer loop e colocar em uma ListView, Column, Row, etc.

Mais detalhes em https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta, nesse caso resolveu em partes o problema, ainda tenho que reiniciar a aplicação( sair e entrar, acho que e um jeito de atualizar a `HomePage`, para que as informações possam sem vistas), teria algum método que atualiza a pagina automaticamente??